# Using disk for IPC in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am struggling with passing a big object between two node.js processes (used fork to create a worker process to offload cpu intensive task).

Basically, when the worker process finishes executing, it writes the js object to disk with `JSON.stringify` and `fs.write`.

Then, the file is being picked up by the main process.

Problem is that `JSON.parse` is blocking and sync so I haven't solved anything here.

Is there any other straightforward format I can use to encode and decode js object to and from disk that could be read in async non-blocking way ?

I'm not looking for best performance necessarily, but for something that won't clog my event-loop

Thanks

Comment: Instead of changing format, can you not just load in an extension that makes async json.parse possible?

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7543